# Progressive form of "have" indicating possession

Tags: grammar, verbs, progressive-aspect

I know that normally I cannot say "I am having a car", but is the following correct?

> Having a car, I decided to drive there.
>
> I am fine with having a car but do not expect me to drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right that we can't use Continuous forms of "to have" (= to possess) as predicates ([finite](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/ru/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/about-verbs/finite-and-non-finite-verbs) forms).

But in your sentences there are ***[nonfinite](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/ru/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/about-verbs/finite-and-non-finite-verbs)*** forms:

Having a car, I decided to drive there. (The ***Present Participle***)

I am fine with having a car but do not expect me to drive. (The ***Gerund***)

So these sentences are  grammatically correct.